# Wal segment still exists on master, but logs on slave and master say it's been removed

Tags: postgresql, replication

I'm trying to set up streaming replication on Postgresql 9.5

The master and slave are configured as below and WAL files are accumulating on the master. However, something is wrong as I get complaints that the WAL files are missing:

Slave:

> FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 0000000200000059000000BA has already been removed

Master:

> repuser@[unknown] ERROR:  requested WAL segment 0000000200000059000000BA has already been removed

The WAL file does exist on the master, and the slave will restore happily if I ship the WAL files over and use the `restore_command` option in `recovery.conf`.

```
postgres$ ls -l /db/archivedir/0000000200000059000000BA
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Mar 31 10:18 /db/archivedir/0000000200000059000000BA
```

Master config - `postgresql.conf`:

```
wal_level = hot_standby
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'test ! -f /db/archivedir/%f && cp %p /db/archivedir/%f'
max_wal_senders = 3
```

The master also has a replication slot configured:

```
brp=# SELECT * FROM pg_replication_slots;
slot_name | plugin | slot_type | datoid | database | active | active_pid | xmin | catalog_xmin | restart_lsn 
----------+--------+-----------+--------+----------+--------+------------+------+--------------+-------------
brp_uk    |        | physical  |        |          | f      |            |      |              |
```

Slave - `postgresql.conf`:

```
hot_standby = on
```

Slave config - `recovery.conf`:

```
standby_mode = on
primary_conninfo = 'host=xxx port=5434 user=repuser password=xxx'
trigger_file = '/tmp/postgresql.trigger.5434'
primary_slot_name = 'brp_uk'
```

Then the `pg_basebackup` is run and the slave started.

The slave has all the data as of the time of the backup, but no new data from the WAL files, and the error above.

What have I mis-configured?

Comment: The streaming replication will look for the WAL in `pg_xlog`, but not the archive directory.  At the same time, the existence of the replication slot should prevent removing the still needed files from `pg_xlog`, so this is at least surprising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as dezso alluded to in the comment. 
The reason you get the error is because the WAL has already been archived.

You can configure how many segments to store on the master with the `wal_keep_segments` configuration. You should set it to at least the amount of WAL's created during the base backup (and some extra as buffer).

Since the standby doesn't connect to the replication slot until it is ready to use it (which is after the base backup is finished), it means that the slot has not been activated yet and therefore is not storing the old WAL's.

Comment: Ah, I'm confusing the pg_xlog and the archive.  I was also confused because after I copied the archive onto the slave it restored from the archived WAL files, but then continued to give the same error (with a later file) Presumably while I was transferring/restoring another WAL got archived and I was in the same situation again.