# Error on PostgreSQL streaming replication

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have the exact same problem as [Wal segment still exists on master, but logs on slave and master say it's been removed](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168750/wal-segment-still-exists-on-master-but-logs-on-slave-and-master-say-its-been-r?newreg=39f9b67c9ae64cf5bd46ce92ac0c518b) except that it is in **Production** !

PostgreSQL 9.4 / Debian Jessie

postgresql.conf:

```
wal_level = hot_standby
max_wal_senders = 5
```

pg_hba.conf

```
host    replication     repl        x.x.x.0/20               trust
```

On the slave replica : Recovery.conf

```
standby_mode = on
primary_conninfo = 'host=<master_server_ip> port=xxxx user=xxxx password=xxxx'
trigger_file = '/var/lib/postgresql/trigger_failover'
```

Error on Master:

```
ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000030000007E00000054 has already been removed
```

Error on slave replica:

```
LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 7E/54000000 on timeline 3
UTC [31252-2] FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000030000007E00000054 has already been removed
```

What can I do to correct it without stopping the production ?

It is not working for several months now, so I guess there is a lot to recover. I can't even find the archives in `./postgresql/9.4/main/mnt/server/archivedir/`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the standby is now several months out of date.  It's probably not useful at this point.  You can replace the standby server with a new basebackup and start up the streaming again.  You may want to look into using replication slots this time to ensure that WALs won't be prematurely removed from the primary.

Comment: Ok thanks Jeremy. I ended up on the same conclusion. I'll look at the documentation to see what is "replication slots" and how to use them.